# What Can I Do If My App Is Rejected Due to Incorrect Language Type?

Tags: huawei-developers, appgallery

After I chose the Chinese mainland as the release country/region of my app that has integrated the HMS Core SDK and submitted the app for review, my app was rejected, for the language for the update pop-up is English, rather than Chinese. Who can help me with this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- If you use Eclipse to integrate the HMS Core SDK, ensure that the
  related multi-language resource packages **are not missing or have not
  been modified**. Generally, the language packages are in the **res**
  directory. Remember not to change the package name.
- If you use Android Studio to integrate the HMS Core SDK, make sure:

1. The downloaded multi-language resource packages (in the **res**
   directory) are not missing or have not been modified.
2. If **resConfigs** has been added to **android > defaultConfig**, the supported languages are the same as the multi-language packages provided by Huawei, especially for **zh-rCN**, which is different from the naming on other platforms.